# MySQL statement - select max from a group

Tags: mysql, sql, count, max, grouping

hi i have the following table, and I want to select the max(count(*)) of plugged for each month. [sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13036/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13036/1)

```
select * from broadcast

profile, plugged, company, tstamp
1,       2,       1,       2013-10-01 08:20:00
1,       3,       1,       2013-10-01 08:20:00
2,       1,       1,       2013-10-01 08:20:00
2,       3,       1,       2013-10-01 08:20:00
3,       1,       1,       2013-10-01 08:20:00
3,       1,       1,       2013-09-01 08:20:00
```

so if I do something like the following:

```
    select plugged, 
           count(*), 
           extract(month from tstamp), 
           extract(year from tstamp) 
      from broadcast 
     where company=1
  group by plugged, 
           extract(month from tstamp), 
           extract(year from tstamp)
  order by count(*) desc;
```

output:

```
plugged, count(*), extract(month from tstamp), extract(year from tstamp)
3,       2,        10,                         2013
1,       2,        10,                         2013
2,       1,        10,                         2013
1,       1,        9,                          2013
```

desired output:

```
plugged, count(*), extract(month from tstamp), extract(year from tstamp)
3,       2,        10,                         2013
1,       2,        10,                         2013
1,       1,        9,                          2013
```

which is right... but I only want the max(count(*))   (for example first row only in this case). There may be scenarios where there are 2 rows with the max count, but for each MONTH/YEAR i only want to return the max count row(s)...do I need an inner select statement or something?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 select plugged, max(counts) counts, month , year
 from 
    (select plugged ,count(*) as counts ,extract(month from tstamp) month , extract(year from tstamp) year from broadcast  where company=1 
      group by plugged,month ,year order by counts desc  ) as x ;
```

Comment: hi thanks!! this works.. but i would like to group by MONTH/YEAR. this one is just doing the total... ill update my question to show my expected result..i updated my question

Comment: you can take a look at my desired output added to the question

Comment: yes ut they are in different months
in October (month 10)   2 plugged have count(2)  and September only 1 Plugged have count(1)